# default a column with empty string

Tags: sql, mysql, default-constraint

Is there a way, via a SQL statement, to ensure a column's default value is an empty string `''` instead of `NULL`?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Yes - use a DEFAULT constraint:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`.`test`;
CREATE TABLE  `example`.`test` (
  `string_test` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Could you use SPACE(0) in a VARCHAR or NVARCHAR column?

Comment: @Randolph Potter: [SPACE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187950.aspx) is a TSQL/SQL Server function - so "No" for MySQL.