# Doctrine2 generating INSERT statement that overrides SQL default value

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm having a similar problem that is explained [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037704/doctrine-inserting-null-values-for-undefined-fields) but the offered solution does not work in my case. Here's the issue...

I am using Symfony2, which uses Doctrine2 for the ORM, to insert new users into the database. When I use the object method to insert the user, a null value is inserted into fields that I don't want to insert anything into (so the default value will be inserted).

This is how I want the generated INSERT statement to look:

```
INSERT into mytable (name) VALUES (?)
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(6) "myName"
}
```

And this is how Doctrine creates the INSERT statement

```
INSERT into mytable (name, token, creationDate) VALUES (?,?,?)
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  string(6) "myName"
  [2]=>
  NULL
  [3]=>
  NULL
}
```

The token should have a default value that is defined using postgresql's uuid_generate_v5 method.  The creationDate should have a default of now().  The NULL values that doctrine is inserting override these default values.

**Is there any way to get doctrine to ignore certain fields on insert?**

Comment: You can put the default value in the constructor of your model object.

Comment: @Nanocom +1 You should not put default values in the database for fields mapped with Doctrine 2. Put the default values in the constructor, or directly in your field declaration.

Comment: Thanks for this.  The reason I haven't used the constructor is because there is other applications using this database, and they use the default values in the db. It would be nice to use the same method for generating the token.  But if it's not possible, then I might need to look into other options.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly using nullable=false attribute in the column annotation.

Comment: Does the field in your database has NOT NULL?

Comment: I tried the NOT NULL on the database field, but I got a 'Not null violation' because it was still inserting NULL.

Comment: Do you think Lifecycle callbacks can be used if the variable is null?

Comment: It would be fine for the creation date, but the token generation is what I am more concerned about.  Ideally the same method should be used to generate the token, no matter which application triggered it.